# Running a java applet from netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, configure

I am trying to run a Java applet from NetBeans, and in trying to run it, I get a 'main class not found' error. I can avoid this by doing SHIFT+F6, but that'll only work if I am currently writing in the main class. I will be working on a somewhat large project, and it's going to have multiple files, and eventually it will be quite cumbersome to always navigate back to the main class to the 'main' file and run it from there. Is there any sort of configurations I can edit to tell NetBeans that I want to run my project (not the individual file) as an applet?
I have NetBeans set up from [this tutorial](http://blogs.oracle.com/pc/entry/how_to_create_applet_with).

Answer (score 6):

In netbeans, right click on the project and chose properties. Under Application > Webstart, there is an option Applet class. specify the full path to your main class (i.e with package names).

Answer (score 1):

Step 1:

[image: step 1]

Step 2:

[image: step 2]

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> to run applet.

Answer (score 0):

This are the `<applet>` parameters that worked for me:

```
<applet codebase="../../build/classes/" code="_package_/_JApplet_.class" width="500" height="500></applet>
```

*Replace `_package_` and `_JApplet_` with your package and applet class.