# How to run an applet in Net Beans with standard run button?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, japplet

Is there a way to run an applet in Net Beans by clicking the run button NOT right clicking and and pressing "Run file" . I am very new to Net Beans.....

Thank you very much for your help,
Regards,

Comment: pssible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054382/running-a-java-applet-from-netbeans

Comment: I tried it but it did not work

Comment: i added a dummy main method. the webstart was trying to launch something but it failed because of security reasons. Check if it works on your system or not.

Comment: But Applet does not need a main method....