# Web Start in Netbeans11 Ubuntu

Tags: java, applet, openjdk-11, netbeans-11

I use netbeans 11 with openjdk 11 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
I want to run applet program, even though it is deprecated, it is part of my college assignment 
☹️
I know that to run applet, you need jdk7/8/older, but previously in Eclipse & IntelliJ I was able to run applet with jdk10, Windows 8.1, so I hope in this case there should be no issues at all. 
I followed instructions given here : [Running a java applet from netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054382/running-a-java-applet-from-netbeans)
I went to project properties > Application > Webstart. But in my system, when I check "enable web start" option and click on OK, still the error "mainclass not found" remains. I figured out that by going again to project-properties > Application > Webstart, the "enable web start option" wasn't tick marked. 
I actually found that everytime I check that web-start option, somehow it is never saved and effectively the option "enable web start" is never get checked. Why is that ? Can anyone suggest reasons ?

Comment: *"even though it is deprecated, it is part of my college assignment"* Since it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). Ask them if it's OK to do the assignment in a panel (a Swing based `JPanel`) which can be displayed in a `JFrame` or `JOptionPane` (ugly, but easier than an applet or frame). They should be fine with that, and if not, you really need to find a better teacher. Note that I'm the top-ranked provider of answers..

Comment: ..  for the [tag:applet] tag, and even ***I*** won't help with them any more.